# Are there better ways to connect to Zookeeper?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

As per APIDOC : 
https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.2/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html

```
public org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.ZooKeeper(
  String connectString,
  int sessionTimeout,
  Watcher watcher) throws IOException
```

Above function accepts connection string which is nothing but CSV of host:port, Which to me looks like hardcoding required at either code/constants/xml/config-service somewhere. But as hosts withing Zookeeper can keep on changing this string can go stale at any point in time and System-Admin to Developer communication to upgrade this might get delays.

**Do we have any other better/dynamic way to connect to zookeeper ?**

Looked at below but all are doing host:port.

1. [connecting to zookeeper in different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706232/connecting-to-zookeeper-in-different-server)
2. [configure Druid to connect to Zookeeper on port 5181](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838992/configure-druid-to-connect-to-zookeeper-on-port-5181)

Comment: Did some code formatting for you. Also, please include the important parts of the linked websites. If they change, your answer becomes rather... ...less useful, to say the least. ;)

Comment: Use an external properties file, sysadmins can then edit this file and change hostnames/ports

Comment: May be Exhibitor project will help? https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Exhibitor-Integration

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs.